# "dlsym" throws a "segment fault" issue sporadically

Tags: segmentation-fault, dlopen, dlsym

Thanks in advance for reading this question.
Our program encountered a strange issue, the "dlsym" throws a "segment fault" issue  sporadically.
The background is, our engine loads multiple share libraries into a single process,  and stores this libraries's handle which got from "dlopen" into a map,

```
 void* handler = dlopen(libraryPath, RTLD_NOW);
if (handler != NULL) {
  handlerStore[libraryPath] = handler;
} else {
  throw exception
}
```

then later call the functions in these library with below code

```
void* handler = handlerStore[toStr(libraryPath)];
typedef int (*function)(); // the function to be called
dlerror(); /**clear error code*/

function f = (function) dlsym(handler, functionName);
char *error = dlerror();
if (error != NULL || f == NULL) {
  throw exception
}

int state_out = 0;
if (f != NULL) {
  try{
    state_out = (*f)();
  }catch (...){
    throw exception
  }
```

The strange behavior is, it works most of the time, but occasionally throws an segment false error with below stack trace.

```
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x35270)[0x7f807d4c0270]
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2(+0x94b0)[0x7f80808fd4b0]
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2(+0x9cfb)[0x7f80808fdcfb]
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2(+0x9fdf)[0x7f80808fdfdf]
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x133e29)[0x7f807d5bee29]
/lib64/libdl.so.2(+0x10d4)[0x7f807c3420d4]
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2(+0xf314)[0x7f8080903314]
/lib64/libdl.so.2(+0x15bd)[0x7f807c3425bd]
/lib64/libdl.so.2(dlsym+0x48)[0x7f807c342128]
```

We are currently struggling on it and really appreciated you can give us some direction

Thanks

Comment: Use `gdb` to find out from the `core` file the value of `handler` and `functionName` at `dlsym`.

Answer (score 1):

> "dlsym" throws a "segment fault" issue sporadically.

Since your program uses exceptions, you should use the term `throw` more carefully: `dlsym` is implemented in pure-C, and does *not* throw anything.

But it `raise`s `SIGSEGV` signal.

The most likely reason for `dlsym` to raise `SIGSEGV` is heap corruption, and the best tools for catching such corruption are [Address Sanitizer](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer) (build with `-fsanitize=address` if using recent GCC or Clang), or [Valgrind](https://www.valgrind.org).